# Using a string in a function in python

Tags: python, string, function, input

I wrote a code to solve a differential problem (here I used a euler method just to check if it works, later I will use RK4 method). But I would like to turn it into a programm where the user input the function `fun` (defined as `dx/dt=fun`). Here my code :

```
from math import*
from pylab import*
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t0=0.0;
x0=1.0;     #conditions initiales
tmax=1.0;   #temps max
h=0.01;     #pas d'integration

N=int(abs(tmax-t0)/h)+1; #+1 pour arriver a T[N]=Tmax

X=np.zeros(N) #indice de n=0 -> N-1 (il y en a N)
T=np.zeros(N)

fun="-6.0*x";

def F(x1,t1):
    x=x1;
    t=t1;
    F=eval(fun);
    return F;

T[0]=t0;
X[0]=x0;

for i in range(1,N):
    T[i]=T[i-1]+h;
    X[i]=X[i-1]+F(X[i],T[i])*h;

plt.plot(T,X,label="Solution");
plt.title('Résolution EDO ordre 1');
plt.xlabel('t');
plt.ylabel('x(t)');
plt.show();
legend()
```

My question is : the function `F` is defined with a `eval` function, and I read it is bad to use that. Have you other propositions ? Thanks !

Comment: You should have a look at `sympy`